# How to detect that i have received an email/gmail on my Android Device?

Tags: android, email, notifications, gmail, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to detect or an event being triggered when i receive a gmail/email on my android device.

Basically i would like my application to read the email notification when i receive it.

Could you kindly tell me if there is way to do this ?

Comment: Don't think gmail provides this for 3rd party apps - and it no longer provides access to already received messages either.

Comment: What is the status as of 2014?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a content observer (not broadcast receiver)

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls"), true, gmailObserver);
```

`gmailObserver` is your own ContentObserver object.

`ContentObserver.onChange` is going to be called every time something changes in Gmail. 
Here you get all conversations like so:

```
Cursor conversations = _contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + YourEmailAddress), null, null, null, null);
```

And the actual conversation messages will be:

```
Cursor messages = _contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + YourEmailAddress + "/" + String.valueOf(conversationId) + "/messages"), null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This looks like the undocumented interface that has been reserved for system apps in the latest version of Gmail, making it no longer available to 3rd party apps.