# Android: Best way to listen to received email

Tags: android, gmail

What is the best way to listen to received emails:
There are apparently different approaches
- JavaMail,
- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html,
- SqlLite Trigger

posts like:
[How to detect that i have received an email/gmail on my Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265351/how-to-detect-that-i-have-received-an-email-gmail-on-my-android-device)
doesn't work

Are there examples of this, which works?

Comment: Please note that any answer we give, if we could give one, will only work for gmail and not for any generic email.  I know a lot of Android users who don't use their gmail account.

Comment: that's ok, Does anyone have experience in this area ?

Comment: I think that might be interesting:  http://androidexample.com/Get_Contact_Emails_By_Content_Provider_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=121&aaid=141,      and       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202403/attempting-to-get-contact-id-using-email-address